# Insert a complex Model Instance into database In Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, model, laravel-5

I am creating an API using Laravel 5.2 and I have a model class named `Post`
when i get a request from client in my `PostController` i have a `JsonObject` like this:

```
{
  "description": "My description is here!",
  "items": [
    {
      "text": "This is the item and the the sort is 0",
      "type": 1,
      "sort": 2
    },
    {
      "type": 2,
      "path": "exmple.com",
      "sort": 3
    }
  ],
  "title": "My title",
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Tag number #1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tag number #2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tag number #3"
    }
  ],
  "user_id": 1
}
```

in my `PostController`

```
 public function store(Request $request) {
    $jsonObject = json_decode($request->getContent());  // i get jsonObject here
    $post= new Post();
    // what to do here?
  }
```

**Relationships**

1. One to One -> User-Post
2. One to Many -> Post-Items
3. Many to Many -> Post-Tags

**What i want to do:**

save this new post using the received `JsonObject` with related data

Note: other model classes like Tag and Item are ready to use.

Comment: Can you please provide these tables columns names. As per your json you can get items by using foreach on $jsonObject->items and same for tags $jsonObject->tags. Save data in respective tables with $post->id in your foreign key.

Comment: @RanjeetSingh thanks for your reply. yes i can save them via iterating in a foreach loop but i think there is better and easier solution for that, isn't it?

Comment: To store ids you can make use of belongsto and belongstomany in your models.